# Windows reduces the CPU load for the terminal when it is minimized. How to change this behavior?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, taskmanager

I noticed that Windows reduces CPU usage for the terminal when it is minimized or on another virtual desktop.

I know this is good practice for overall resource management for the operating system, but I need that specific application (terminal in this case) to have resources allocated as if it were open.

I have already tried changing the power saving settings to "high performance" and tried changing the process priority to higher values, but I can only notice an actual increase in allocated resources when the terminal is open. When minimized, the priority increase appears to have no effect.

Is there an effective way to resolve this limitation?

P.S.
The measurements are performed trivially with the task manager. The executable that I call from the terminal encodes a video (ffmpeg) that is very heavy in terms of bitrate, all done with multicore and parallel calculation. With the terminal in the foreground the processor is perpetually around 100%, as soon as it is minimized it switches to variable percentages, from 7 up to a maximum of 30%. As soon as it is reopened in the foreground, just a few seconds later it resumes full power and returns to full load.
I tried with the same hardware with a Linux system and this problem does not occur.
I tried with other hardware with Windows 11 and the problem is the same.
Both with old and new versions of ffmpeg.

Comment: What exact observations or measurements have you made? How exactly is the application's behavior affected?

Comment: Performance should be better when window is minimized.  The view is not automatically repainted.  When window is maximized there may be a delay do paint items.  Maybe is what you want is to paint items when window is minimized.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies.
I'll update the post above so it's clearer for everyone.